# Reduce table overall size with pandoc.table

Tags: r-markdown, pandoc, pander, ioslides

I am rendering a table in RMarkdown (ioslides) using pander and pandoc.table but only 6 out of 10 rows are showing. How do I reduce the table size to see all rows?

```
employee <- c('A','B','C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'H', 'K','L', 'M')
salary <- c(1, 2, 3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
employ.data <- data.frame(employee, salary)
panderOptions('table.split.table', 300)
pandoc.table(head(employ.data), style = "multiline", keep.line.breaks = TRUE, split.table = Inf, size.table = 0.50)
```

But the table only shows 6 rows in the table, not 10! Can anybody help please? Thank you.

Comment: Maybe remove the `head` call filtering down to the first 6 rows?

Comment: Thank you, that worked, it's showing now 8 rows. But it's still not wrapping the table nicely on the slide.